# Ansible | extract a part of line

Tags: ansible, line, extract

I want to extract a part of a line.

eg. line: `-Dlogging.configuration=file:/ngs/app/dsservt/TEST/DS/IdmsCoreServiceClassic/13443/runtime/jboss/standalone/configuration/logging.properties -jar /ngs/app/dsservt/TEST/DS/IdmsCoreServiceClassic/13443/runtime/jboss/jboss-modules.jar -mp /ngs/app/dsservt/TEST/DS/IdmsCoreServiceClassic/13443/runtime/jboss/modules org.jboss.as.standalone -Djboss.home.dir=/ngs/app/dsservt/TEST/DS/IdmsCoreServiceClassic/13443/runtime/jboss -Djboss.server.base.dir=/ngs/app/dsservt/TEST/DS/IdmsCoreServiceClassic/13443/runtime/jboss/standalone`

Expecting extracted output:

`/ngs/app/dsservt/TEST/DS/IdmsCoreServiceClassic/13443/runtime/`

Im not sure how to achieve this.

Please help me.

Comment: How it is related to Ansible?

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expression

```
\/ngs.........................................................\/
```

https://regex101.com/